Why does Visual Studio Code/Python not show the docstring for functions from my PyPI package?
I have recently created my own PyPI package with a bunch of useful functions. It works great, and when I import it in any project, the functions work, but my Visual Studio Code doesn't show the docstrings when I hover over the functions, and the functions stay white.
Are there Python Visual Studio Code settings I need to change or things I need to change in my PyPI package?

The GitHub place for jeffutils.
I have tried setting the "python.analysis.packageIndexDepths" depth for "jeffutils" to 4, and I added from .utils import * into the __init__.py file in the package.
Other than that, I am kind of lost, since Pylance and the Python interpreter will pop up docstrings for all of the other pip-installed packages I have.

Can't reproduce. Try using another machine (e.g. a GitHub codespace), then compare that with your current environment.

@InSync I appreciate that advice. In GitHub codespace, it pops up everything like normal. What things can I do to look at the codespace environment and compare it with mine?

Try turning on settings sync and start from there. Other than that, I have no idea.

@InSync Thanks for your help! Going through item by item and making sure Python and Pylance settings matched seemed to fix it!

Following InSync's advice, I compared my Pylance and Python extensions settings with the settings in GitHub Codespaces.
I made sure everything matched up the same. The things I recall changing was getting rid of my Python → Analysis:Extra Paths (I had paths to a couple of Python binary files on my CPU), and then pip uninstalling and reinstalling the jeffutils package.
I wish I knew what fixed the problem, but following InSync's advice worked!
